# php mysql code won't echo

Tags: php, mysql

I got the following code:

```
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) { $query = "SELECT * FROM watchlist,movies WHERE watchlist.page=movies.id AND userid=". $_SESSION['user_id']; 
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

    while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) )
      {
        echo '<div id="watchlist">';
            echo '<a href="watch.php?id='.$row['page'].'"><img src="http://nocmmnt.com/posters/'.$row['imdb_id'].'.jpg" height="217" width="154"></a><br>';
            echo '<span style="float:right;"><a href="delete.php?wid='.$row['wid'].'"><img src="image/close_delete.png" width="20"></a></span><a href="watch.php?id='.$row['page'].'">'.$row['title'].'</a><br>';  
            echo "</div>";
      }
    elseif(empty($row)) {
        echo "You dont have any movies in your watchlist!";
    }
```

My problem is that is doesnt echo when its empty how can I fix that?

Comment: You want to echo when no result found? if yes then what you want to print? use mysql_num_rows for checking empty rows.

Comment: A curly closing bracket is missing - fix that first.

Comment: Where's the `if` for the `elseif`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that :

```
   if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
  { echo "You dont have any movies in your watchlist!"; }
  else{
  while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) )
  {
    echo '<div id="watchlist">';
        echo '<a href="watch.php?id='.$row['page'].'"><img src="http://nocmmnt.com/posters/'.$row['imdb_id'].'.jpg" height="217" width="154"></a><br>';
        echo '<span style="float:right;"><a href="delete.php?wid='.$row['wid'].'"><img src="image/close_delete.png" width="20"></a></span><a href="watch.php?id='.$row['page'].'">'.$row['title'].'</a><br>';  
        echo "</div>";
  }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
elseif(empty($row)) {
```

That's wrong conditional structure, an `elseif` must come after an  `if` block or another `elseif`.

How can that code not generate a parse error for you?

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSEIF on line 13
```

Also, as others mentioned, simply check for row count being 0

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
mysql_num_rows($result)
```

to check if there are 0 rows or more than that.

Answer (score 0):

Checking `empty($row)` doesn't do what you think it does. What you want to check is `mysql_num_rows($result) == 0`.

A sidenote - `mysql` is deprecated in favor of [`mysqli`](https://www.php.net/mysqli).

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your code as below, also try to use mysqli instead of mysql

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) { $query = "SELECT * FROM watchlist,movies WHERE watchlist.page=movies.id AND userid=". $_SESSION['user_id']; 
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($count > 0 )
    {
        while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) )
        {   
            echo '<div id="watchlist">';
            echo '<a href="watch.php?id='.$row['page'].'"><img src="http://nocmmnt.com/posters/'.$row['imdb_id'].'.jpg" height="217" width="154"></a><br>';
            echo '<span style="float:right;"><a href="delete.php?wid='.$row['wid'].'"><img src="image/close_delete.png" width="20"></a></span><a href="watch.php?id='.$row['page'].'">'.$row['title'].'</a><br>';  
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "You dont have any movies in your watchlist!";
    }
}
?>
```